# String filter ignoring regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, filter

I want to filter a list of Strings but ignoring regular expressions. For example: Looking for "test.xy" should only show entries like "test.xy" or "abctest.xy" but not "testaxy". I dont want "." working as a wild card.

How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to accept any string that **contains** "test.xy"? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-. The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: Please, give us a more detailed explanation of the problem. What is the regex or the format? Do you want to apply it or neglect it?

Comment: sry, I try to be more specific. I want the filter to completely ignore regular expressions. I don't want the filter to show entries like "ab" or "aa" when I'm filtering the list by the keyword "a."

Comment: You can just use any method that does not interpret the needle as regex.

Comment: sry, my example in the start post was wrong. I edited a correct one.

Comment: It still holds, use any method that does not interpret the needle as regex but just as string. Which holds for most methods. So pretty much everything except `split` and `replaceAll` (`replace` is non-regex) and `Pattern` with `Matcher`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("test.xy", "abctest.xy", "testaxy", "testy");
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.contains("test.xy"))
                System.out.println(s);
        }

        // Display using Stream
        System.out.println("\nFilter and display using Stream:");
        list.stream().filter(s -> s.contains("test.xy")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
test.xy
abctest.xy

Filter and display using Stream:
test.xy
abctest.xy
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my example was wrong. I edited it in my start post. Now it should be more clear what I was looking for. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter the strings and collect them in a new list you can do it as follows;

```
    List<String> strings = List.of("mytest.xy",
            "abctest.xy", "test.xy", "testaxy", "testy");
    String target = "test.xy";
    List<String> result = strings.stream()
            .filter(str -> str.contains(target))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

> mytest.xy 
>   abctest.xy 
>   test.xy